# Site reachable using cell phone LTE but not home cable connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, cable-modem

I have a website that is accessible when I use my cell phone using the cell service LTE for the internet. However, my home cable connection can't connect to the same website. When I switch from LTE to for my home wifi, it can't connect. So the issue here is networking. When I do nslookup on the subdomain and I get the correct IP address. So it's not a DNS issue. There is nothing blacklisted and there is nothing ip bound. It just one network (cell network) can access but my cable connection at home can't (Comcast if it makes any difference).

I'm not a network engineer. Any theories as to how to debug this?

Comment: It sounds like you only tested from your phone.  Did you try from a computer?

Comment: yes.  I did.  Both mac and windows desktop.  Neither of them can connect using Wifi.  This happens to some people (me included) but not to others.

Comment: What about Ethernet?

Comment: if others on the network can get to it, then its not a network issue.

Comment: So we're dealing with a single IPv4 address and no IPv6 (no AAAA records)? Is this HTTP or HTTPS or both? Can you telnet to port 80 (or 443)? Can you ping the address? How do the failing-case traceroutes compare to the working-case traceroutes? For any hops that only show as an IP address, use `whois` to see who owns them.

Answer (score 0):

Many things can block a connection from a PC.

1) Your firewall app is designed to block connections to problem websites. Perhaps the firewall thinks you should be blocked for safety? That site might have had a problematic file in it, or the firewall service might have gotten an erroneous warning.

2) **C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts** (Windows) and **/etc/hosts** (MacOS X) contains a list of domains pointed to 127.0.0.1 and if the desired site is listed in that file, removing that line from the file will solve the problem.

3) The home router might block traffic from that website to that PC's ports; whichever service provider manages the home router might have a false (or true) bulletin warning of malicious activity from that site. After you have checked 1) and 2) above, have a chat with Comcast. Take a Xanax first, you may need it.